# Textmate and vim modes

Tags: macos, vim, textmate

It is possible to emulate vim modes, macros and bindings in textmate?

Comment: <from a long time vim user> Why would you want to do that?

Comment: What, pray tell, are mac roses?

Comment: I am interesting for mac but I can't live without vim.

Comment: SMiX: Vim 7.2 is pre-installed on OS X 10.6.  Earlier versions are included other versions of OS X.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used to love TextMate, but changed to Vim after finally giving it a chance.  I'm somewhat amused that ViMate exists.  However, in my experience, `vi` input modes are kinda hit-and-miss.  (Example: viper mode in `emacs`.  It's close, but not enough to make me start to use `emacs`.  Also, the system-wide keybindings for OS X.)  I'll be interested to see how it turns out.

If what you're looking for is a "Mac integrated Vim" through TextMate, you might try [MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/) too.  It's the real Vim, but it has Mac keybindings and looks prettier.  :)  (It's like `gvim`, but written in Cocoa, I believe.)

Comment: np :)

If you want Terminal.app to be prettier, you might also look at TerminalColors.  See also:  http://blog.infinitered.com/entries/show/8

Answer (score 6):

You can use ViMate.

http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/27072

This is the list of features already implemented in ViMate. Hope this helps.

#### Implemented

Movement

- k - moveUp
- j - moveDown
- l - moveForward
- h - moveBackward
- w - moveWordForward
- b - moveWordBackward
- e - moveToEndOfWord
- 0 - moveToBeginningOfLine
- $ - moveToEndOfLine
- ## [movement] - move # number of times

Insert

- a - insertForward (not repeatable)
- i - insertBackward (not repeatable)
- o - insertBelow (not repeatable)
- O - insertAbove (not repeatable)

Cut

- d - cutSelection
- dd - cutLine (not repeatable)
- dl,x - cutForward (not repeatable)
- dh,X - cutBackward (not repeatable)
- dw - cutWordForward (not repeatable)
- db - cutWordBackward (not repeatable)
- de - cutToEndOfWord (not repeatable)
- d0 - cutToBeginningOfLine
- D,d$ - cutToEndOfLine

Copy

- y - copySelection
- yy - copyLine (not repeatable)
- yl - copyForward (not repeatable)
- yh - copyBackward (not repeatable)
- yw - copyWordForward (not repeatable)
- yb - copyWordBackward (not repeatable)
- ye - copyToEndOfWord (not repeatable)
- y0 - copyToBeginningOfLine
- y$ - copyToEndOfLine

Change

- c - changeSelection
- cc - changeLine (not repeatable)
- cl - changeForward (not repeatable)
- ch - changeBackward (not repeatable)
- cw - changeWordForward (not repeatable)
- cb - changeWordBackward (not repeatable)
- ce - changeToEndOfWord (not repeatable)
- c0 - changeToBeginningOfLine
- c$ - changeToEndOfLine

Paste

- P - pasteBefore (hacky near end of file)
- p - pasteAfter (hacky near end of file)

Scroll

- ctrl-e - scrollLineDown (not repeatable, doesn't keep caret in view)
- ctrl-y - scrollLineUp (not repeatable, doesn't keep caret in view)
- ctrl-f - scrollLineDown (not repeatable, doesn't keep caret in view)
- ctrl-b - scrollLineUp (not repeatable, doesn't keep caret in view)

Answer (score 1):

@TK Here's the complete list of ViMate commands from [Starving Cyclist](http://starvingcyclist.com/vimate):

```
Movement:
k - moveUp
j - moveDown
l - moveForward
h - moveBackward
w - moveWordForward
b - moveWordBackward
e - moveToEndOfWord
0 - moveToBeginningOfLine
$ - moveToEndOfLine
#[movement] - move # number of times
Insert:
a - insertForward (not repeatable)
i - insertBackward (not repeatable)
o - insertBelow (not repeatable)
O - insertAbove (not repeatable)
Cut:
d - cutSelection
dd - cutLine (not repeatable)
dl,x - cutForward (not repeatable)
dh,X - cutBackward (not repeatable)
dw - cutWordForward (not repeatable)
db - cutWordBackward (not repeatable)
de - cutToEndOfWord (not repeatable)
d0 - cutToBeginningOfLine
D,d$ - cutToEndOfLine
Copy:
y - copySelection
yy - copyLine (not repeatable)
yl - copyForward (not repeatable)
yh - copyBackward (not repeatable)
yw - copyWordForward (not repeatable)
yb - copyWordBackward (not repeatable)
ye - copyToEndOfWord (not repeatable)
y0 - copyToBeginningOfLine
y$ - copyToEndOfLine
Change:
c - changeSelection
cc - changeLine (not repeatable)
cl - changeForward (not repeatable)
ch - changeBackward (not repeatable)
cw - changeWordForward (not repeatable)
cb - changeWordBackward (not repeatable)
ce - changeToEndOfWord (not repeatable)
c0 - changeToBeginningOfLine
c$ - changeToEndOfLine
Paste:
P - pasteBefore (hacky near end of file)
p - pasteAfter (hacky near end of file)
Scroll:
ctrl-e - scrollLineDown (not repeatable, doesn't keep caret in view)
ctrl-y - scrollLineUp (not repeatable, doesn't keep caret in view)
ctrl-f - scrollLineDown (not repeatable, doesn't keep caret in view)
ctrl-b - scrollLineUp (not repeatable, doesn't keep caret in view)
Visual Mode:
V - highlight line
v - visual mode
Repeat:
1,2,3... - repeat next command (buggy)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [VicoApp](http://vicoapp.com). It's similar to textmate and has support many Vim key-bindings.